# PHP "Resource ID#5".

Tags: resources

I am doing a small project for myself, never touched PHP before and I am still learning from the Internet.

When I am sending something like this via MySQL query in Myphpadmin I just get my variable what I want. But when I send same thing via .php script:

```
$pkt = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id =4 AND meta_key='mycred_default'");
echo "".$pkt."";
```

It's giving me "Resource ID#5" instead of echo my pkt variable. That's pretty weird for me because at myphpadmin I am getting what I want.

Comment: I suggest you start reading the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php And especially the part about the `mysql_query()` function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php Doing so will answer your puzzlement, especially when you take a look at the examples in there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `mysql_query` doesn't give you any data - it merely gives you a resource (in this case #5). In order to get the actual data, you can use `mysql_fetch_row`, for example:

```
$pkt = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id =4 AND meta_key='mycred_default'");
list($result) = mysql_fetch_row($pkt); 
echo "$result";
```

Comment: Working like a charm. Thanks you! I can't vote up because I am new here.

Comment: Just do the same here too, as you did mine @user3565273 ;-)